# Электронный компас BNO080

Tags: arduino, stm32, compass

Проводил эксперименты с модулями ориентации BNO055 и BNO080, меня в них интересует точное нахождение севера для дальнейшей ориентации робота, но проблема в том что от этих модулей можно получить высокую точность лишь в одном месте, переместив датчик вдоль края стола на 1 метр я получаю ошибку в 10 - 15 градусов, а перемещая по комнате порой датчик ошибается на 40 градусов.
Как получить высокую точность (без накопления погрешности) для мобильного робота?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Вы будете вашим магнитометром находить стальные балки, каркасы зданий, электропоезда метрополитена и дедушкин телевизор.

Лучше стереовидеокамеры и алгоритмов класса structure-from-motion для навигации в помещении вариантов практически нет.

Вне помещения это можно дополнить любой GNSS.